# jQuery Ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, request

I am trying to get the following code to send variables to a PHP page via POST. I am not quite sure how to do it. This is my code sending data via GET and receiving it via JSON encoding. What do I need to change to pass variables to process_parts.php via POST?

```
function imagething(){
    var done = false,
    offset = 0,
    limit = 20;
    if(!done) {
        var url = "process_parts.php?offset=" + offset + "&limit=" + limit;

        $.ajax({
            //async: false, defaults to async
            url: url
        }).done(function(response) {

            if (response.processed !== limit) {
                // asked to process 20, only processed <=19 - there aren't any more
                done = true;
            }
            offset += response.processed;
            $("#mybox").html("<span class=\"color_blue\">Processed a total of " + offset + " parts.</span>");
            alert(response.table_row);
            console.log(response);
            imagething(); //<--------------------------recursive call
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

            $("#mybox").html("Error after processing " + offset + " parts. Error: " + textStatus);

            done = true;
        });
    }
}
imagething();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default method is `GET`, to change that, use the `type` parameter. You can also provide your querystring properties as an object so that they are not immediately obvious in the URL:

```
var url = "process_parts.php";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit
    } 
}).done(function() {
    // rest of your code...
});
```

Comment: Once I have added that, how do I specify what post variables get passed to the PHP?

Comment: They would have been passed in the querystring. I've amended my answer to show you how to include them in post data.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
         $.ajax({
                    url: "URL",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify(ty),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },

                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert('Failed');
                        alert(x.responseText);
                        alert(x.status);
                    }
                });
```